# Joining Tables in a ColdFusion Query

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfml, railo, lucee

I am executing two queries to build a table off of data from two tables in the same database.   The code I have now is below, but I know I am creating an unnecessary load doing it this way.  I have been trying to join the tables to get the same result, but have had no luck.  Any input?

```
<cfquery name="GetWeekends">
   SELECT id, weekend_type, community_id, start_date, end_date, language
   FROM _weekends
   WHERE weekend_type = 1 and start_date > Now()
   ORDER BY start_date ASC
</cfquery>  

<cfloop query="GetWeekends">                
    <cfquery name="GetCommunity">
        SELECT community_id, location, language, state, country
        FROM _communities
        WHERE community_id = #getweekends.community_id#
    </cfquery>                  
    <tr>
        <td>#DateFormat(start_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")#</td>
        <td>#GetComm.location#</td>
        <td>#GetComm.state#</td>
        <td>#GetComm.country#</td>
        <td>#GetComm.language#</td>
   </tr>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: So what have actually you tried and how was the result different than what you expected? :) BTW, a [`JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) simply connects two tables on a shared key or column, which in your case appears to be "community_id". If you have not tried anything yet, take a look at the example in the wiki article. It is very clear and should be easy to adapt by substituting your table and column names.

Comment: I was just trying to use a JOIN to make it more efficient.  Al E's answer nailed it :-)

Comment: (Edit) Well, I was hinting that you should post what you tried, so we could help you fix it (and hopefully understand the problem better) rather than just posting the answer outright ;-) Still if you are uncomfortable with joins, I would definitely recommend spending some time learning about them, since they are *very* fundamental part of SQL that you will use ... a LOT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Database joins are pretty basic. You'd do well to educate yourself about them.

In any event, it looks like you want to do something like this:

```
<cfquery name="GetWeekends">
SELECT w.id, w.weekend_type, w.community_id, w.start_date, w.end_date,
  w.language,
  c.community_id, c.location, c.language, c.state, c.country
FROM _weekends w
  INNER JOIN _communities c
    ON w.community_id=c.community_id
WHERE w.weekend_type = 1 and w.start_date > Now()
ORDER BY w.start_date ASC
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Awesome!  I have been trying to wrap my head around them, and sometimes looking at it being used in the code you are working with causes the lightbulb to go on. Thank you!!